# Are there any bots here other than Community and Feeds?

Tags: support

I saw two bot users so far on this site: Community (-1) and Feeds (-2).  So I have a question: are there any bot users on this site other than the two?

Comment: Feeds as far as I know is not a user, but an automated process. There are many, many automated process that are both user facing and non user facing and any actions taken should just show up as the community.

Comment: Community is also an automated process

Comment: I know there are a bunch in the codegolf chats, but haven't seen any around here.

Comment: https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1374/obscurerobot, but I guess we'll never know whether the many users with "robot" in their names are human or not...